# Embedding live dhis2 data directly on your website

Tags: dhis-2

I want to display the charts, tables, maps etc from a dhis2 user account unto a web page. I read the web api documentation and tried to use the plugins but they dont work (they seem to be outdated). Anyone have a solution to this?

Comment: can you please explain what you did and the problem faced?

Answer (score 0):

You may use the Web APIs of dhis2 to fetch data , and then use any Library for building graphs out of that data.